# How to repeat a character in Bourne Shell?

Tags: unix, sh

I want to repeat `#` 10 times, something like:

```
"##########"
```

How can i do it in Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`) ? I have tried using `print` but I guess it only works for bash shell.

Please don't give bash syntax.

Comment: `perl -e 'print "#"x10'` maybe?

Comment: echo | awk '{ for (i=0; i<10; ++i) printf "#" }' works for me. Thanks @Tripleee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell itself has no obvious facility for repeating a string.  For just ten repetitions, it's hard to beat the obvious

```
echo '##########'
```

For repeating a single character a specified number of times, this should work even on a busy BusyBox.

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=10 count=1 | tr '\0' '#'
```

Not very elegant but fairly low overhead.  (You may need to redirect the standard error from `dd` to get rid of pesky progress messages.)

If you have a file which is guaranteed to be long enough (such as, for example, the script you are currently running) you could replace the first 10 characters with `tr`.

```
head -c 10 "$0" | tr '\000-\377' '#'
```

If you have a really traditional userspace (such that `head` doesn't support the `-c` option) a 1980s-compatible variant might be

```
yes '#' | head -n 10 | tr -d '\n'
```

(Your `tr` might not support exactly the backslash sequences I have used here.  Consult its man page or your local academic programmer from the late 1970s.)

... or, heck

```
strings /bin/sh | sed 's/.*/#/;10q' | tr -d '\n'  # don't do this at home :-)
```

In pure legacy Bourne shell with no external utilities, you can't really do much better than

```
for f in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do
    printf '#'
done
```

In the general case, if you can come up with a generator expression which produces (at least) the required number of repetitions of something, you can loop over that.  Here's a simple replacement for `seq` and `jot`:

```
echo | awk '{ for (i=0; i<10; ++i) print i }'
```

but then you might as well do the output from Awk:

```
echo | awk '{ for (i=0; i<10; ++i) printf "#" }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the pure Bourne Shell (POSIX) solution, without pipes and forks would probably be

```
i=0; while test $i -lt 10; do printf '#'; : $((++i)); done; printf '\n'
```

This easily generalizes to other repeated strings, e.g. a shell function

```
rept () {
  i=0
  while test $i -lt $1; do
    printf '%s' "$2"
    : $((++i))
  done
  printf '\n'
}
rept 10 '#'
```

If the HP Bourne Shell is not quite POSIX and does not support arithmetic substitution with `: $(())` you can use `i=$(expr $i + 1)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick with `printf`:

```
$ printf "%0.s#" {1..10}
##########
```

If the number can be a variable, then you need to use `seq`:

```
$ var=30
$ printf "%0.s#" $(seq $var)
##############################
```

Comment: Neat!  Unfortunately, the `{1..10}` syntax is a Bash extension.

Comment: Oh, is it? I never know where to check this... Then, the `seq` should make it.

Answer (score 0):

This prints `##########`:

```
for a in `seq 10`; do echo -n "#"; done
```

Comment: Error: /bin/-sh: seq:  not found.

I'm working on Bourne shell (/bin/sh), will the above syntax work?

Comment: `seq` is a fairly standard utility.  It's not a feature of your shell.  If you don't have GNU `coreutils`, what *do* you have?  A common *BSD replacement is `jot`.

Comment: Not sure, i'm working on HP NONSTOP_KERNEL, how can i check it?

Comment: The kernel doesn't decide which utilities you have installed.  If this is an extremely limited environment, perhaps you should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: I apologize for not making it clear, but is there any other way by which this can be achieved ?